# Installing the REGEX module for Mac

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to install Regex for Python3 using pip install regex  but when I try to import the package into my python programs it cannot find the package.
Please can someone help me with installing regex for python3?

Comment: Try `pip3 install regex`.

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct `pip` command for your python. Easiest way to ensure that is to run `python -m pip` instead.

Comment: Does it shows installation successful ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are facing this problem on mac, you might have not installed the appropriate version of the Command Line Tools - XCode for your Mac OS. Install it using:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After this, you can install regex by:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade regex
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a mac and have had the same issue in the past. Try this:

```
sudo python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade regex
```